# Delphi - Does Treeview Data Objects need to be freed?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, treeview

Delphi 2010 - I have a Treeview with approx 2000 nodes.  Each node has a Data Object, which points to a record.  When I exit my program, does the memory associated with the Data objects get automatically freed, or do I need to traverse each node a DISPOSE of them?

Comment: You need to free only if you're the one who created the objects behind the data. What you create, you need to make sure is free'd. What the system creates the system will free. The `Data` properties have no concept of what you're putting in them, they're just pointers.

Comment: Put your records in a TList<T> and at program termination, just walk the list and free your items. If you use objects then TObjectList<T> is more appropriate with the added bonus that the objects will be freed for you the moment you destroy the list.

Comment: Yes, and yes. The memory occupied by the objects will be freed because it's returned to the OS when you exit the program, but you should free the objects.

Comment: @TLama, yes that is correct. IMHO, I would never leave any leak unhandled :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy, I wouldn't do either; I missed to address the second part of the question :) Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data` property of the `TTreeNode` class is intended for you to use for your private needs. It is an untyped pointer and that gives you the freedom to put whatever you like in there.

As a corollary to the property being an untyped pointer, the control cannot know what type of thing you put in there. And hence it cannot destroy it, even if it wanted to.

So yes, you do need to make sure that the memory you allocated is destroyed. Essentially you are the owner of that memory, the control does not own it.

How you go about doing that is of course entirely up to you. One option would be to have a separate container that owns the data associated with each node. Then you can delete the container and let it delete the data.

That might be inconvenient if you have a complex tree structure that is hard to replicate in the containers available to you. In that case you might choose to customise the tree view to create nodes of a type that you define. That custom node type could take charge of allocating and deallocating the data. The [`OnCreateNodeClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.OnCreateNodeClass) is the key to making this happen.

Comment: Let me make sure that I understand this one point.  Even though my program creates objects (specifically nodes use data property pointing to records), when my program exists, unless I have DISPOSED of these entities, via OnCloseQuery or similar, Windows will not "de-allocate" this memory?  Correct?

Comment: The OS will claim it back at process shutdown time. The OS claims everything back then.

Answer (score 3):

Having found this question via a Google search and not finding the solution I have just used, I have decided to put an answer even though the question is a couple of years old.

TTreeView has an OnTreeDeletion method which is called as each node in the tree is deleted giving the opportunity to free/dispose of any associated data.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TfmMyForm.MyTreeDeletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
var
  rci: TRecentCodeItem;
begin
  rci := node.data;

  if assigned(rci) then
    freeandnil(rci);
end;
```

I store a pointer to an object of type TRecentCodeItem with the node.

One difference between my situation and the questioner's is that my tree view was not on the main form so I couldn't just leave it to windows to mop up the memory after the application closes.  Not that I would do that anyway - I do like to have zero memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data gets freed once you exit your program since the objects reside in the same memory space of the process your application runs in. It is good practice to free them manually anyway using `Object.free` or better yet `FreeAndNil(object)`.

Comment: `Free` and `Dispose` are not interchangeable.

Comment: You fixed it the wrong way. Pointer to record. So it needs `Dispose`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, you *can* store an object in a `TTreeNode`. It is probably better practice to store objects rather than pointers to records in the first place, *e.g.* `MyClass := TMyClass.Create;` and later `TMyClass(Node.Data).Free;`

Comment: Actually I know that. I said in my answer, "It is an untyped pointer and that gives you the freedom to put whatever you like in there." But since the asker stated clearly and explicitly that what was in the node was "pointer to record", your advise to call `Free` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I use this soulution, maybe it helps someone in future:

```
TTreeViewItemEx<TData: class> = class(TTreeViewItem)
private
    _dataObject: TData;
public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property dataObject: TData read _dataObject write _dataObject;
end;

destructor TTreeViewItemEx<TData>.Destroy;
begin
    if Assigned(_dataObject) then
        _dataObject.Free;

    inherited;
end;
```

usage:

```
procedure UsageExample;
var
    node: TTreeViewItemEx<TData>;
begin
    node := TTreeViewItemEx<TData>.Create(treeView);
    node.DataObject := TData.Create;
    node.Parent := treeView;
end;
```